# Can Zap scan a web app launched as a JAVA applet?

Tags: java, zap, applet

I have a target which is a Java applet. When I reach the IP in the browser and enter credentials into a form, a .jnlp file downloads, which I need to double-click on to access the page.
Does Zap have support for scanning this types of Web apps? 
Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: The "page" is not served over the network, so a HTTP proxy is not the right tool for the job

Comment: @schroeder With all due respect, I don't think this is correct. From https://fileinfo.com/extension/jnlp: "JNLP files are used for launching and managing Java programs over a network or on the web (e.g., an applet in a web browser)."

Comment: Is the java app launched and served over the network, or is it downloaded locally and run on the local machine?

Comment: @schroeder The app is run locally, but it makes calls over the network.

Comment: So then any proxy is only going to be able to capture what is actually sent. And that's not likely to be HTTP, right?

Comment: @schroeder  The app is a web client, only that it's locally run not in the browser, but as a Java applet. I captured the traffic, it's over TLS. I'll post a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Per: https://java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml
For a Java Applet the proxy details can be set via the Java Control Panel.

**Configure Proxies through the Java Control Panel**

1. In the Java Control Panel, under the General tab, click on Network Settings.
2. Select the Use Browser Settings checkbox.
3. Click OK to save your changes.

[image]

4. Network Settings for the Java Control Panel
5. Close all browser windows. Restart the browser and try to load the applet.
6. If the applet still does not load and you see the same connection error, 
   try to configure your web browser's proxy settings.

So yes you should be able to configure either Java or your Browser to use ZAP in order to capture and manipulate the traffic from a Java Applet.